# MYSQL about Hash index type index is ignore sometimes

Tags: mysql, indexing, hash

I have a column with a index of type Hash with has value from 1..128

Like this

```
CREATE INDEX indexName ON myTable (studentType) USING HASH;
```

Sometimes we have queries like this.

```
Select * from myTable where studentType =1;
Select * from myTable where studentType =2;
```

Here the index is used very good but I was reading the docs and some stuff really caught my attention, I think maybe I didn't get it well.

> Only whole keys can be used to search for a row. (With a B-tree index, any leftmost prefix of the key can be used to find rows.)

Does this mean that if I have a query like this:

```
Select * from myTable where studentType =2 and status=121;
```

Here MySQL is ignoring the hash index 'studentType'? because the where clause uses other column besides the column index? Or what it says in a example.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB has no `HASH` index.  Your declaration was turned into `BTree`.

Either of these BTree indexes works just fine for your last `SELECT`:

```
INDEX(studentType, status)
INDEX(status, studentType)
```